# Remove Administrator

Tags: admin

We had a Magento site built for us a while back by a local developer but he has just vanished. We do not have any of his login details, only a few accounts with limited access to the backend and cannot do many of the things we need to be able to do to keep the site running properly.

Is there a way we could get in or create a new admin account with full access?

Comment: Whatever you do, DO NOT REMOVE the Magento installed administrator account or change its role from being given full access. You will have major issues down the road when user 0 gets tampered with.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to have access to phpmyadmin or mysql command line using SSH connection.

Follow this link to change password for user: **admin**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password

You can also reset all passwords for all magento users using this query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX')
```

The new password will be "password"
if you want to have a different password, change only the "**password**" word in SQL query.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily, we control the hosting so have access to all that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to the ftp ? if yes you can reset the admin password programmatically.

Follow the steps to change the password programatically.

Lets create a file and name as resetpassword.php with the following content

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('admin')->setPassword("yourpassword")->save();

echo "Successfully Changed";
?>
```

Replace the parameter admin from loadByUsername('admin') with the actual username uploaded this file to the server where the magento folder structure is their.Then run this file like http://www.urlofwebsite.com/resetpassword.php

Now you have successfully changed the password and you can login with your new password